# Exporting the List of columns and list for values for that columns to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of ID's which i'm looping through and i'm getting the List of FIELDS and VALUES.

Now i have to put both the list into Excel file where FIELDS are the Columns and VALUES are the rows for that columns **as i said there is List of ID's** its means every id have different VALUES but the Fields are same. and VALUES should have the list/dict or anything what ever we find in value list we will put it into excel.

for that i have tried with these code:

```py
field_nameList = []
field_valueList = []

for id in IDS:
    for field in id:
        field_value = id[field]

        ..... some code........

        field_name = id[field]

        ..... some code........

        field_nameList.append(field_name)
        field_valueList.append(field_value)

# Here after getting all the ID's Fields and Value i'm converting it to dictionary to export it to excel using pandas.

fieldsItems = dict(zip(field_nameList, field_valueList)) 
df = pd.DataFrame(fieldsItems)
df.to_excel('GXfile.xlsx', index=None,header=True)
```

For single ID its worked but when i have multiple ID's and then i'm trying to do the same i'm getting

> Error:Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

My main motive is for every id whatever list i'm getting I need to create a columns and from next loops onwards just keep adding the row for the FIELDS.

I know maybe my code implementation is not correct but please suggest me a better way.

Added Fieldname which is columns name here and the values this is the sample excel data

```
Id  Resolution  subStatus           Last Viewed                     Σ Original Estimate Issue Type  CCB Decision    Reason For Escalation   CCB Comments    Issue Service Affecting?    Estimated Effort to Fix Reproducibility Problem Description/Systems Impacted    Symptoms    Release Note Status Release CCB Estimated Effort to Verify Fix
1   None        Screening Required  2020-01-30T06:38:45.668+0000    144000           Bug        Fix     Defer           ccb testing Yes             test                                        Never       test            test        Unspecified 
2   None        Screening Required  2020-01-30T06:38:45.668+0000    144000           Bug        Fix     Defer           ccb testing Yes             test                                        Never       test            test        Unspecified
```

@The Guy i'm sorry for not explaining properly i appreciate the help and code but there one misunderstanding here i have 3 list first list is for ID's in that other 2 list which i'm getting dynamically from code so let me write again:

First list :

```
ID = [1,2,3,4..]
```

2nd List:

```
Field_Name =['A','B','C',...so on] this will be achieved by code
```

3rd List:

```
Field_value =['A_values','B_values','C_values,....so on]
```

Excel File should contain:

```
ID  A         B         C          ....
1   A_values  B_values  C_values   .....
```

Here we can clearly see that i'm getting the Fields_name as a columns and Filed_value as a row for that particular columns ...how we can get this.

Comment: please add how your field_nameList and field_valueList is looking.

Comment: ohk let me add @TheGuy

Comment: @TheGuy please refer the excel in which i'm getting the columns name from list and and values from list same way i'll get multiple values for the same FIELDS at last when my loop ends i need to put all of them into Excel my col list really big to paste here so i have copied only few please let me know if you have any other doubt..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your updated post:

```
import pandas as pd

ids=[1,2,3]
Field_Name =['A','B','C']
Field_value =['A_values','B_values','C_values']

zipped_name_and_value=dict(zip(Field_Name,Field_value))

df=pd.DataFrame([zipped_name_and_value])
df.index+=1

df.index.names=['Id']
```

**Output**

```
       A          B           C
Id          
1   A_values    B_values    C_values
```

In above case Id is not coming from list.

If you want all three lists ids, Field_Name, FieldValue should be used, in that case following is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

ids=[1,2,3] 
Field_Name =['A','B','C']
Field_value =[['A_values','B_values','C_values'],['A_values','B_values','C_values'],['A_values','B_values','C_values']]


df=pd.DataFrame(Field_value,index=ids,columns=Field_Name)
```

**Output**

```
         A          B         C
Id          
1   A_values    B_values    C_values
2   A_values    B_values    C_values
3   A_values    B_values    C_values
```

**Note**: You have to make sure that the Field_Value has nested list, because all the nested list will be treated as row.

Comment: please see the latest edit Thanks for your code i really appreciate it but i need to get in different way please help me with that...Thanks

Comment: @snehilsingh i have updated the post. Let me know if this works for you or not.